# Javascript append URL in image source

Tags: javascript, variables

I am attempting to append an image source which does not reside on our server to reference and external server. Specifically this 4th line.

[image of 4th line of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJVxD.png)

I need this to reference an external server and not default to my default server. And suggestions?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#thumbs ul li').click(function() {
        var imgpath = $(this).attr('dir');
        $('#image').html('<img src=' + imgpath + '>');
    });
    $('.btn').click(function() {
        $('#thumbs').fadeIn(500);
        $('#image').animate({
            marginTop: '10px'
        }, 200);
        $(this).hide();
        $('#hide').fadeIn('slow');
    });
    $('#hide').click(function() {
        $('#thumbs').fadeOut(500, function() {
            $('#image').animate({
                marginTop: '50px'
            }, 200);
        });
        $(this).hide();
        $('#show').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The src attribute in your img tag is unquoted. Try this:

```
$('#image').html('<img src="' + imgpath + '">');
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized my mistake, I went in a different direction. Instead creating a new variable called "linkpath" and append the image source.

```js
var imgpath = $(this).attr('dir');
var linkpath = "http://www.website.com";
$('#image').html('<img src=' + linkpath + / + imgpath + '>');
```